# InDesign: I need a repeating image on every page, and paragraph styles with a variable aren't working

Tags: adobe-indesign, master-page

I have a lot of sub-chapters and each sub-chapter needs to have on each page an image. I was thinking of putting the image on the first page of the sub-chapter and set to paragraph style A. Then create a running header variable for that p-style and put the variable in the master.

Everything without creating a master page for each sub-chapter...

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you'll find a better way, but if you don't, and if it's a monochrome vector image you need, you may need to use the same cumbersome technique needed to use custom images as bullet points:

[IndyFont Demo: make your own (1 character) font](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5055048#5055048)

([Better step-by-step instructions from Lynda](http://blog.lynda.com/2012/09/13/indesign-secrets-creating-your-own-custom-bullet-character/))

([Better writeup on Typophile](http://www.typophile.com/node/94235))

Basically it's a quick and easy way to create one-character document fonts within InDesign, to use as textual icons etc. Quick summary:

- Get the free [One-Character Demo of Indesign-based font maker IndyFont](http://www.jongware.com/binaries/indyfont_demo.zip)
- Install it as any indesign script.
- In the Indyfont bit of the Script panel, 'Create font template'
- Paste in `[Black]` vector artwork. The red line is the base line, adjust the green line to make space.
- Save...
- If you're in Indesign CS5 or above, you can include it as a [document font](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WSa285fff53dea4f8617383751001ea8cb3f-6e29a.html#WS328f5ee33f08f77d1e63e3d123e8d1b40b-8000) (in a folder called 'Document Fonts' next to your `.indd`) without having to install it system-wide.